# How to upload a file using protractor tool when button is defined as ng-flow type of control

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

The browse button is created using the ng-flow library, and the `input=tagname` and `type=file` for the button is set programmatically, and is not seen anywhere in the HTML view of the page. So I am not able to find the element at runtime, for which I can use the `sendKeys` command to set the path of the file.

[image]

Comment: There have to be an `input` element with `type="file"` anyway - it is probably hidden - look for it carefully.

Comment: as @alecxe said try to look for input field if it is not found, then use "AutoIt" tool to upload file.

Comment: Thanks All, AUTOIT resolved my problem.